# Active Record Has And Belongs To Many Alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having a difficult time understanding how to go about attaching an alias of Owner to a User in relation to a Club when a join table is involved. I trying to build an app where a user can create a club and add other users to that club.

A User **has many** Clubs as an owner and **belongs to** many Clubs as a member.

A Club **has many** users who are members and **belongs to** a User who is its owner.

I want to be able to get the following information:

```
user.clubs => Returns all clubs the User is a member of
user.clubs_as_owner => Returns all the clubs they own
club.owner => Returns the User Jane Doe
club.members => Returns the Users: Jane D., Ashley K., Marry P.
```

.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_clubs
  has_many :clubs, through: :user_clubs, :class_name => "Club",
                            :foreign_key => "member_id"

  has_many :clubs_as_owner, through: :user_clubs, :class_name => "Club",
                                     :foreign_key => "owner_id"
end

class Clubs < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_clubs
  has_many :members, through: :user_clubs, :class_name => "User",
                              :foreign_key => "user_id"

  has_one :owner, through: :user_clubs, :class_name => "User",
                           :foreign_key => "user_id"
end

class UserClubs < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :club
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Generate migration:

```
  def change
    add_column :clubs, :user_owner, :integer # user id as owner

    create_table :club_users, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :club, index: true
    end
  end
```

And try something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clubs,
                          :class_name => 'Club',
                          :join_table => 'club_users',
                          :foreign_key => 'club_id',
                          :association_foreign_key => 'user_id'
  def self.clubs_as_owner
    Club.all.where('owner = ?', self.id)
  end
end 

class Clubs < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users,
                          :class_name => 'User',
                          :join_table => 'club_users',
                          :foreign_key => 'user_id',
                          :association_foreign_key => 'club_id'
  def self.owner
    User.find(self.user_owner)
  end
end

club.users
user.clubs
user.clubs_as_owner
club.owner
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :clubs_as_owner, class_name: "Club", foreign_key: :user_id
   has_and_belongs_to_many :clubs, join_table: :memberships, foreign_key: :user_id, association_foreign_key: :clubs
end

#join table -- memberships - user_id | club_id

#app/models/club.rb
#columns id | owner_id | x | y | z | created_at | updated_at
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
   has_and_belongs_to_many :members, join_table: :memberships, foreign_key: :club_id, association_foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@user = User.find x
@user.clubs #-> all clubs user is a member of
@user.clubs_as_owner #-> all clubs user is an owner of

@club = Club.find x
@club.members #-> all users with membership at club
@club.owner #-> user who owns club
```